# Understanding the relationship between a 'sufficient statistic' and an 'unbiased estimator'

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics

Can anyone give an explanation in laymen's terms of what the relationship is, if any, between a sufficient statistic and an unbiased estimator?

Is it not true that both allow us to know something about an unknown parameter $\theta$? I think a sufficient statistic allows us to learn about a sample and the value of an unknown parameter about which we want to make some sort of inference.

And I think that an unbiased estimator gives us the most accurate estimation possible for some unknown population parameter, given information from a sample.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'accurate'. An unbiased estimator might have high variance, and a biased estimator might have very low MSE. If I always shoot an arrow 5mm to the left of the target, that may be much better than half the time shooting 500mm left and the other half shooting 500mm right -- - small bias-small variance beats zero bias-big variance in general. (Why is unbiasedness of itself especially useful? For a given variance, clearly unbiased is better than biased, but we're rarely in that situation)

Comment: @Glen_b: (+1) I completely agree with this assessment. Unbiasedness is only a relative notion in terms of optimality, useful to fnd a "best" estimator by restricting the class of estimators. There exist sufficient estimators that are terribly biased and unbiased estimators that are far from sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

Sufficiency is an essential if rare property: if $S(X)$ is sufficient for model $f_\theta$, considering $S(X)$ for estimation of $\theta$ is *sufficient*, meaning you need nothing else from $X$. In other words, the collection of estimators based on $S(X)$ cannot be improved by other estimators [in the sense of any convex loss function].

Unfortunately, sufficiency only exists in exponential families. That is, if the density is of the form$$f_\theta(x)=\exp\{ \sigma(x)\cdot \Phi(\theta) - \psi(\theta)\}h(x)$$ then for a sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $$S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma(x_i)$$is sufficient. Outside exponential families there is no sufficient statistic $S_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in\mathbb{R}^d$ with fixed dimension $d$ [fixed in $n$] (this is the [Pitman-Koopman-Darmois theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic)).

On the other hand, *unbiasedness* is a local property that does not lead to optimality per se. Optimality does depend on the loss function used for comparing estimators and restricting the class of estimators to unbiased estimators can only increase the optimal error.

For instance, in the estimation of a multivariate normal mean vector, when $x\sim\mathcal{N}_d(\mu,I_d)$, under squared error loss, admissible estimators, i.e. estimators that cannot be beaten uniformly over $\mathbb{R}^d$, are all biased. In other words, an unbiased estimator of $\mu$ $\delta_0$ is inadmissible: there always exists a biased estimator $\delta_1$ (and in fact an infinite number of biased estimators) such that$$\mathbb{E}[||\mu-\delta_1(X)||^2]\stackrel{\ne}{\le}\mathbb{E}[||\mu-\delta_0(X)||^2]$$

For further information, I suggest reading [Lehmann and Casella](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985026) on this topic.

Comment: The Pitman Koopman Darmois lemma only applies to distributions with fixed support. When the support is parameter dependent, there may exist families with a sufficient statistic of fixed dimension, regardless of the sample size $n$.

Comment: Here "fixed support" doesn't mean to exclude -Inf to Inf support, only exclude parameter dependency, right? And regarding my first comment, for a fixed sample size, the sufficient statistics has also fixed dimension, yes? Is it the sample itself, or is the dimension of the statistics is a function of the number of samples?

Comment: I do not understand the question about fixed dimension for a fixed sample size. In any situation but the exponential families the dimension of any sufficient statistic need grow with the size of the sample.

Comment: Fixed support means that the support does not vary with the value of the parameter. This excludes densities with indicators like $\mathbb{I}_{[\mu,\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that if the dimension of sufficient statistic grows with the size of the sample, then in the worst case the sufficient statistic is the sample itself. Or does it mean even the entire sample is not enough if the distribution is not exponential family?

Comment: In the worst (i.i.d) case a sufficient statistic is the order statistic vector. For example for the Cauchy distribution. It is of dimension $n$ but removes the ancillary permutation that is the rank statistic.

Comment: The whole sample is sufficient but the order statistic which is not in bijection with the whole sample is also sufficient, this means a reduction in variability if not in dimension.